# restruct document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have documents structure in mongoDB like this.

```
{
'identifier': 'testanalysis',
'uuid': 'abc',
'days': [{'day': 20190122, 'value': 1}, {'day': 20190123, 'value': 2}, ]
}，
{
'identifier': 'testanalysis',
'uuid': 'xyz',
'days': [{'day': 20190122, 'value': 5}, {'day': 20190123, 'value': 10}, ]
}
```

I hope to get a result as follows.It seems like group by `day` and combine `uuid` and `value` as an object.

```
{
    'day': 20190122,
    'result': [
        {'uuid': 'abc', 'value': 1},
        {'uuid': 'xyz', 'value': 5},
    ]
}，
{
    'day': 20190123,
    'result': [
        {'uuid': 'abc', 'value': 2},
        {'uuid': 'xyz', 'value': 10},
    ]
}
```

Comment: May be you are looking for aggragation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/ and projections https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just little bit [Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: '$days' },
  { $group: {
      _id: "$days.day",
      day: { $first: "$days.day" },
      result: {
        $push: { 'uuid': '$uuid', 'value': '$days.value' }
      }
    }
  }
])
```